# Timeline key frame spaces beetween many object position animation

Tags: animation, sequence, frame, timeline

Hello guys I try to make a building animation like all parts arrive in order . [BEFORE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wpey.png) [AFTER](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WI7hO.jpg) . I have like 600 seperated parts like that, Is there an easy way do that? Right now I'm making manually every part

Sequence animation layers and frame gaps every object animation